# Hook Advance Search Form

Tags: hooks, search

I want to hook the Drupal advance search form for add more filter criteria,

I want to add the below criteria
1) Search By Post Date
2) Search Between Post Date
3) Search by last day, last 7 days

I applied the hook Mymodule_search_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {} to add the fields,

Please You suggest me Guys that how can i alter the search query, i am looking for this by last 2 days, but nothing found

This is the link that i got only

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575289/extending-drupal-7-search

But that not works,

Any suggestions Please...!!

Answer (score 0):

To alter the query itself, try [hook_search_api_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!search_api.api.php/function/hook_search_api_query_alter/7) (for search api) or [hook_search_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) for the core search

Comment: Can You Provide Further Instructions, how to implement as i found nothing in my search module

Comment: I updated my answer (missed half the sentence, sorry) - I have never modified the search query, so this is as much as I can provide - a search should yield more information on how to implement these

Comment: i already execute that but that create the separate path for my custom module that i created for hook, i want to merge my fields with the advance form fields & make it searchable..i wasted my weeks or so, but still cant find nothing...

#by d way Thanks

Comment: you can add form elements via hook_form_alter, but you would then need to run your own query update to include that information, presumably through hook_search_execute and reference the new form elements you create